creating an egrep command clone with C optimization error
I am working on a C program to implement regex-like pattern matching using the KMP (Knuth-Morris-Pratt) algorithm. However, I am encountering an issue where the program produces an incorrect output, even though I expect matches based on the input provided.
Here’s my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Match any character ('.')
int match_any(char c) {
    return c != '\0'; // '.' matches any character except the end of string.
}

// Recursive function to evaluate pattern with '*' (star operator)
int match_star(const char* text, const char* pattern, char prev_char) {
    // Try zero repetitions first (move directly to the next pattern)
    if (regex_match(text, pattern)) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Try one or more repetitions of the previous character
    while (*text && (*text == prev_char || prev_char == '.')) {
        text++;
        if (regex_match(text, pattern)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// General recursive regex matching function
int regex_match(const char* text, const char* pattern) {
    // Debug print
    printf("Matching pattern '%s' with text '%s'\n", pattern, text);

    if (*pattern == '\0') return *text == '\0'; // End of pattern and text match

    // Handle grouped sub-patterns inside parentheses
    if (*pattern == '(') {
        const char* end = strchr(pattern, ')');
        if (!end) return 0; // Invalid pattern (no closing parenthesis)

        // Extract and process the sub-pattern inside the parentheses
        char subpattern[1024];
        strncpy(subpattern, pattern + 1, end - pattern - 1);
        subpattern[end - pattern - 1] = '\0';

        if (!regex_match(text, subpattern)) return 0;

        // Continue matching after the parentheses
        return regex_match(text, end + 1);
    }

    // Handle alternation (|)
    if (strchr(pattern, '|')) {
        const char* alt_pos = strchr(pattern, '|');
        char left[1024], right[1024];

        // Split around '|'
        strncpy(left, pattern, alt_pos - pattern);
        left[alt_pos - pattern] = '\0';
        strcpy(right, alt_pos + 1);

        // Check both sides of the alternative
        return regex_match(text, left) || regex_match(text, right);
    }

    // Handle repetition (*) for the previous character
    if (*(pattern + 1) == '*') {
        return match_star(text, pattern + 2, *pattern);
    }

    // Handle '.' (any character) case
    if (*pattern == '.') {
        if (*text == '\0') return 0; // No match at the end of the string
        return regex_match(text + 1, pattern + 1);
    }

    // Direct character match
    if (*text == *pattern) {
        return regex_match(text + 1, pattern + 1);
    }

    // No match
    return 0;
}

// Function to search for the pattern in each line of a file
void search_in_file(const char* pattern, const char* filename) {
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Error: Could not open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    char line[1024];
    int line_number = 1;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove newline character
        // Debug print to ensure we are reading lines properly
        printf("Checking line %d: %s\n", line_number, line);
        if (regex_match(line, pattern)) {
            printf("Match found on line %d: %s\n", line_number, line);
        }
        line_number++;
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <filename> <pattern>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char* filename = argv[1];
    const char* pattern = argv[2];

    search_in_file(pattern, filename);

    return 0;
}

Input file (input.txt):
hello world
he*llo
abc123
a.b.c
alpha and omega
aaabbbccc
12345

I am running the program with the command:
daarkmp.exe input.txt "a*b"
What I get in output:

I added debug print statements to track the lines being read and the patterns being matched, but still no output.
I verified that my input file is correctly formatted and accessible.
Does anyone have insights into why my pattern matching logic might not be working? Are there common pitfalls I should check for in regex implementations in C?

Please [edit] to show current output as text (not as am image) and also the expected output. From looking at the code it would appear that regex_match is always returning zero. Perhaps add more debug prints at various points throughout regex_match to show progress through the code and also the values being tested. The declarations of subpattern, left and right as 1024 char arrays are worrying as there do not seem to be any checks that they are big enough.

The match for line 3 of abc within abc123 appears to be working OK at first. The first three characters are matched leaving the empty pattern not matching 123. The code
if (*pattern == '\0') return *text == '\0'; // End of pattern and text match

appears to say that an empty pattern (or a pattern where everything has been matched so far) can only match an empty string.
Comparing the code to common RegEx styles, it would appear that the code is putting an implicit $ (i.e. end of string) at the end of the pattern. I wonder whether it is also working as if there is an implicit ^ (i.e. start of string) at the start of the pattern.
I think that adding another example that checks abc against abc will produce the Match found on line ... message.
